# Post-measurement $\psi$ in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, measurements, observables

I have a question regarding the wave function after a measurement. Everything I found online says that this is the following formula:

$\psi = \frac{M_m\psi}{\sqrt{P(m)}}$

Where $P(m)$ is the probability of observing m, the $\psi$ on the left is the wavefunction AFTER the measurement and the $\psi$ on the right is the original wavefunction. However, I cannot find a good definition on how I would go about calculating $M_m$? The Berkley lecture notes say that this is the measurement operator, but how would I go about finding that for my specific problem?

Also the probability function is $P(m) = |<\psi|\omega>|^2$, how would I find $\omega$ in this case? Is it just the eigenstate at that observable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about what a measurement is in QM. Generally speaking, you are going to measure an eigenvalue of an observable. Lets say that you measure $A$ that follows the eigenstate equation $A|a>=a|a>$. Then if you begin with a general state $|\psi>$, after the measurement you will get another state $|\psi'>$ following the equation:

$$|\psi'>=\frac{|a><a|\psi>}{\sqrt{P(a)}}$$

Where $|a><a|$ is called the projector (or measurement operator by your lectures). It basically gives you the part of $|\psi>$ that is in the subspace of eigenstates of eigenvalue $a$.

Physically it means that after a measurement is done, you can be sure that the state of the system is in a subspace with eigenvalue $a$, so that any other measurement of the obsevable $A$ that you make on the system afterwards will spit out the eigenvalue $a$ all the time (if you keep the system unchanged).

So you if you want to calculate $M_m$, which is the projector into the subspace of some eigenvalue, just find the eigenstates of that eigenvalue (lets say $A|a_n>=a|a_n>$ for $n=0,1,...,g$). Then.

$$M_m=\sum_{n=0}^{g}|a_n><a_n|$$

Answer (score 0):

It is instructive if you work with some simple setups. Consider the example of a spin-half system where you’re measuring the spin along the z-axis. We know that the possible outcomes are either up or down. So in general your Say your pre-measurement state is a normalised linear combination:
$$|\psi\rangle=\alpha|u\rangle+\beta|d\rangle$$

What this says is that probability of observing the state to be up when measured is given by:
$$P(u)=\big|\langle u|\psi\rangle\big|^2=|\alpha|^2$$
And the probability to observe a down state under spin measurement is similarly given by:
$$P(d)=\big|\langle d|\psi\rangle\big|^2=|\beta|^2$$
Remember that after measurement of any observable the state will always be in **exactly** one of the eigenstates. Like in this example, the state after measurement is either up or down. And not a linear combination of the two.

Answer (score -1):

The physical interpretation is fairly simple, even though it is not often being explained in the literature and in lectures. We start with a quantum mechanical ensemble that can be described by an initial wave function psi_i. After the measurement we have a new ensemble with wave function psi_f (f for final). The physical measurement that changes one ensemble into the other has removed quanta with an energy of E=E_i - E_f.

In practice: start with a bunch of atoms in an excited electronic state. Wait for half of those atoms to decay by sending out photons of energy E. The new ensemble now contains half as many excited atoms as the old one. The measurement operator of the physical vacuum is, of course, energy independent. Free space will "absorb" any photon energy that the atoms want to emit. But what if we put these atoms in a cavity that only allows a narrow frequency band to escape, i.e. the "measurement device" has an absorption spectrum itself? Then only atoms can decay that fall into this narrow absorption band. All other atoms can not leave their excited states any longer. The energy will always stay in the ensemble because no quanta of any other energy than allowed by the spectrum of the measurement device can be lost.

If you read Heisenberg's matrix mechanics papers, you will find this sketched out in the math. Somewhere along the way to the Schroedinger equation and von Neumann's solution theory this rather simple physical interpretation got lost and we are all wondering what a measurement operator spectrum is supposed to mean. It means just that: the eigenvalues and eigenvectors that describe the absorption bands of the measurement system.

Curiously, my first theoretical physics teacher taught us this principle on a musical example from classical physics. It's a device for cellos called a "Wolftoeter" in German or "Wolf tone suppressor" in English. It removes an unwanted resonance of the strings of the instrument. The initial cello sounds rough, the eliminator takes the energy of the resonance tones out and the final cello sounds smooth.